# Set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as an Environment Variable in Windows permanently

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

How can I permanently set the environmental variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` on `WINDOWS` on a permanent basis and be done with it?

I mean

1. `Win Button` + `Pause/Break Button`
2. This leads to `Control Panel\System and Security\System`
3. Click `Advanced System Settings`
4. Click `Environment Variables`
5. There are two boxes the first is titled `User variables` and the second `System variables`
6. On the `System variables` click the `New Button`
7. For variable name put in `DJANGO_IMPORT_SETTINGS`

**XXX-->** **WHAT DO I PUT IN VARIABLE VALUE TO SET IT ONCE AND FOR ALL?**

---

In the Django Site on this [issue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/) it states:

*DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE*

*When you use Django, you have to tell it which settings you’re using. Do this by using an environment variable, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.*

*The value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be in Python path syntax,e.g. mysite.settings. Note that the settings module should be on the Python import search path.*

---

What does it mean ***...should be in Python path syntax e.g. mysite.settings...*** ?

- I have a certain directory where my `Python` is located:
  `C:\Python27`
- I have a certain directory where my `Django` is located: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django`

What does this `mysite` means. What directory is it meanning `C:\Something......`

Can you put this variable once and for all or you have to constantly change it for every project (I hope not!)

And what does this suspiciously line means ***Note that the settings module should be on the Python import search path.***

**All I want it to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environmental variable and be done once and for all from this hassle**

**EDIT**

*In order to work, Django just has to be pointed at a valid settings file, and by default it
looks for an environment variable named DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to tell it where to find the
settings. The value of this variable should be the Python import path of the settings file, such
as cms.settings.*

--> What king of directory is this: `cms.settings`? In windows every directory starts with a hard drive as **C:\Something.....**. How can you start a directory like this in Windows?

**EDIT_2**

Excerpt from a book

*PROBLEM*
*Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.*

*SOLUTION*
*Run the command `python manage.py shell` rather than `python`.*

**MY QUESTION** --> ON WHAT DIRECTORY?///CAN YOU SET IT FOR ONCE OR IS IT DIFFERENT PER PROJECT?

MY PROJECT IS STRUCTURED LIKE THIS

```
C:\Python27\pysec-master(file)
|__local_settings.py
|__manage.py
|__settings.py
|__C:\Python27\pysec(file)
   |__ __init__.py
   |__example.py
   |__models.py
   |__xbrl.py
   |__xbrl_fundamentals.py
```

I am trying to run `models.py` and I have a `settings.py` in the `C:\Python27\pysec-master`
You can find an exact copy [here](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec).

**MAYBE_IMPORTANT_EDIT**

I have a file called `manage.py` in my project which has these contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Does this has to do anything on setting the variable? Do I need to set here here inside the loop?

EDIT

For the command in the IDLE `from django.db import settings` do i need to set a directory for the `PYTHON_MODULE_SETTINGS` like `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db` ?

Comment: Can you have one `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` permanently or you must change her for every project? Somebody...i am stuck for days on this...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, don't be so frustrated. Let's look at this step by step:

- **Python path syntax:**

  In Python, when you split your code base across modules, you qualify the name of the import with the name of the module. Let's say your project is structured like this:

  ```
  my_project
  |__utils
  |  |____init__.py
  |  |__file_utils.py
  |__my_module
     |____init__.py
     |__main.py
  ```

  In your `main.py` if you want to access methods you have defined in `file_utils.py` you add  an import statement in your `main.py` like this:

  ```
  import utils.file_utils.read_file
  ```

  assuming `read_file` is the method you want to import into `main.py`. This way of importing modules where you have a `.` separating every module is referred as python path syntax.
- **PYTHONPATH:**

  In the above example, the import statement would work only if the Python interpreter knows where to look for the first module namely the `utils`. Only when it finds `utils` can it find `file_utils` and `read_file`. You specify the list of all the paths you want the interpreter to look into in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. So in order to have an import statement like above in your code, you have to make sure that the full path to your project `my_project` is in `PYTHONPATH`. Assuming `my_project` is in `C:\AMAZEBALLS_CODE\my_project` you should have `C:\AMAZEBALLS_CODE` in your `PYTHONPATH`
- **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:**

  Now let's suppose your `my_project` is actually a Django application. A Django application needs a settings file where you specify a [whole bunch of things](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/). In order to instruct Django which settings file to look into you specify it in `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. Assuming this is your project structure:

  ```
  my_project
  |__utils/
  |  |____init__.py
  |  |__file_utils.py
  |__my_module/
  |  |____init__.py
  |  |__main.py
  |__site_settings/
     |__dev_settings.py
     |__production_settings.py
  ```

  `myroject.site_settings` is the module Django has to look into for the settings file. And `myroject.site_settings.dev_settings` is the value you need to be setting to the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in the above case. When documentation says `cms.settings` or `mysite.settings` they mean `cms` or `mysite` is the name of your project and `settings.py` is the name of your settings file.

Now let's look at your question:

Can you permanently set it in the environment variables of Windows? Sure.
Is it the right way? No.

Because if you want to create another application tomorrow in another location, you will have to edit this in the environment variables section of Windows. Also, it is a practice to use a different settings file for development environment and another one for production. So setting it at one place with one value makes it inflexible. But if you are aware of all of the above and sure you are gonna be using just the one settings file set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `myproject.site_settings.dev_settings` in the env variables section.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Looks like you are putting your `pysec-master` project in `C:\Python27`. Do not put your projects in the python installation. Create a `settings.py` file in your project and set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `pysec-master.settings`

Comment: Sorry for the slow response time i am looking analytically the answer.

Comment: So if `pysec-master` is my projects name i must input it as      `pysec-master.settings` on the `IDLE` or the `cmd`? If it is on the `cmd` i must go to that directory and then type it to `cmd`? I will try that one out and then i will try on `IDLE` in Python

Comment: Yes i have my project in my `C:\Python27` file. As a beginner i thought it was the most sensible thing to do. It seems it isn't. Changing the location now...

Comment: Dear shaktimaan, on the EDIT i have changed the location of the `pysec-master` file and the relevant environmental variables. However the project i have downloaded from github has a `settings.py` so i think i might not have to make one.

Comment: You have stated: Set you DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to `pysec-master.settings` well two hot questions... 1) On the `cmd` or the `IDLE` and 2) Do i put the directory for `pysec_master.settings` like `C:\pysec-master.settings`?

Comment: Must i set it inside the `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> All i want it to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environmental variable
>   and be done once and for all from this hassle

If you don't want to go through a tedious procedure every time, you don't have to make it permanent, you only need to make the procedure automatic.

Create a bat and put `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='xxx.settings'` inside.

If you are using virtualenv, you can set the environment variable in bin/activate.bat.

Comment: Sorry but i do not now what is a `bat` file ( i will find that out though). You have said: `'xxx.settings'` and my question is: Dont you have to put the directory that leads to my project which is `pysec-master` on a `Windows` environment?-like `C:\pysec-master.settings... Is the last one i said correct?

Comment: Must i set it inside the `settings.py` file?

Comment: Do i need to put the windows directory `C:\pysec-master` and then settings?