# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK

Tags: django

Why do I have the following problem when running tests? Tried everything already, nothing seems to work:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Everything is working, but the testing.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't provide the full picture of the project structure so I am  going to pin point what would usually cause this problem :

**1.** install pytest-django

```
$ pipenv install --dev pytest-django
```

**2.** create a file to define the settings module, and name it
**pytest.ini**

> ```
> [pytest]
>
> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=storefront.settings
> ```

replace "storefront" with your root folder and make sure the ***spelling*** is right , also this file should be on the root directory along side with the `manage.py` file .

**3.** in the terminal type pytest , remember to execute this command in the root directory (the same place you `$ python manage.py runserver`)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by installing the `pytest-django` library in my environment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

check your installed apps in the project settings file and ensure that you have the `REST_FRAMEWORK` added and it doesn't contain duplicates or other errors

Comment: Here are my installed apps: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'api',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
] Everything is all right

Comment: they look alright, the error statement mentions the `You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` [check this out if it will solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23157955/6236465)