# Getting Relative Import Error While Registering Models Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-settings

I was following the django documentation tutorial to make my first app, and then I reached the admin.py part and was trying to register my models, but then I got this error:

`Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

My Folder Structure:

```
├───Poll
│   └───__pycache__
└───polls
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    └───__pycache__
```

Visual Representation:

[image]

My Code in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Question, Choice

admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'members.apps.MembersConfig',
]
```

Comment: This post provides additional details that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156500/set-django-settings-module-as-an-environment-variable-in-windows-permanently 
It provides background information that includes what that error message is pointing you toward. 

This looks to me to be caused by an issue with how you installed Django and how you set the Django project up. One way to troubleshoot is to trying and start a new project with a new virtual environment to see if you can replicate the issue. Other elements include what IDE you're using.

Comment: @HamTheMan Can you add settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

I could see one problem  i.e. import should be either from current location, using `.` or specify some app name.

Through current location:

```py
from .models import Question, Choice
```

Through app name:

```py
from some_app_name.models import Question, Choice
```

Comment: I tried using . while importing, it still did not work

Comment: @HamTheMan Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074690/improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-installed-apps-but-settings-are-not-con) question, also It can't be imported like as you imported even you can also see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/).

Comment: It was in the django documentation, so I assumed it would work

Comment: @HamTheMan `from models ....` makes no sense, it should be `from .models ...` or `from some_app_name.models ...`.

Comment: I tried both ways, I'm not sure what went wrong. I basically followed the django tutorial all the way through. Think i'm going to just give up on it

Comment: @HamTheMan Which Django version you are using?  4.1?

Comment: I'm using 4.11, the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after many frustrating hours. Basically in `admin.py` you register the model and instead of running the file, type py `manage.py runserver`.

Here's an example:
Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

admin.site.register(Person)
```

Instead of running the file separately, do this:

CMD:

```
cd yourproject
py manage.py runserver
```

And It works.